Drupal/mailsystem installed but menu item still not showing up on the menu screen
Hello I'm a bit of a Drupal newbie (long time admin but new to drupal). I tool over management of some existing sites. I'm trying to add the mail systems menu item to configure an SMTP relay and doesn't seem to be working.
I have run composer require 'drupal/mailsystem:^4.5', composer require 'drupal/phpmailer_smtp:^2.2', composer require 'drupal/symfony_mailer:^1.5' and they seem to be showing up in composer show:
drupal/mailsystem                        4.5.0   Mail System
drupal/symfony_mailer                    1.5.0   Symfony Mailer
drupal/phpmailer_smtp                    2.2.6   Uses the PHPMailer library to send emails via SMTP.
I'm not sure were else to go with this, seems like the modules are installed at this point so not sure why its not showing in the site. What else can I check or look?
Thanks,
Doug

Well this worked faster than I expected!!
Right after I asked I saw the extend menu, I had looked her under "add new module" but didn't notice that the already installed ones are listed on the main page and needed to "checked" for the option to show.....
Taking some time but we'll get there.
